# How do I modify these VPN connection settings for Xfce?

Tags: xfce, vpn

I have signed up for a VPN (Virtual Private Network) service, and I configured it for use on my computer that runs Gnome Classic with the following instructions:

```
In Terminal, install openvpn packages with sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn.
1. Restart the network manager with sudo restart network-manager
2. Run sudo wget https://www.xxxxxxx.com/ovpnconfigure.zip
3. Extract the files from the zip with unzip ovpnconfigure.zip.
4. Move cert.crt to /etc/openvpn
5. Open the Network Manager on the menu bar.
6. Choose add and select the OpenVPN connection type, and click Create.
7. Enter Private Internet Access SSL for the Connection Name.
8. Enter xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com for the Gateway
9. Select Password and enter your login credentials.
10. Browse and select the CA Certificate we saved in Step 3.
11. Choose Advanced and enable LZO Compression.
12. Apply and exit.
13. Connect using the Network Manager.
```

It worked, but now I want to set up access to the same VPN service on another machine that runs Mythbuntu, which uses Xfce as its desktop manager. So every point from 5 on doesn't apply.

How can I modify the above instructions so that I can get my VPN service working with Xfce.

As a further note, while I can access the Xfce desktop directly if I need to, it's more convenient for me to access it via the command line and SSH from on of my other computers. A command line process would be ideal. (I looked for this, and found instructions only for PPTP access, whereas I need OpenVPN.)

Comment: Are you saying Mythbuntu doesn't have the network manager? Most XFCE distros actually use exactly the same Gnome NM as found in Gnome. If it really isn't there, just install it.

Comment: @mikewhatever: what is the command I can type in on the command line to run the network manager?

Comment: Don't know what's the command. If installed, it should start at boot. I'd suggest verifying it is by running `dpkg -l | grep network-manager`.

Comment: @mikewhatever: I have a few network-manager results if I run that command. But I guess what I was asking was how do I start the GUI interface (the one used in the instructions in the question) from the command line.

Comment: I don't have Mythbuntu installation to check, but isn't there an icon in the panel or a Network entry in the menus?

Comment: @mikewhatever: Oh... maybe. As I mentioned in the question, it's easier to access the Mythbuntu machine by command line via SSH. In order to be at the desktop directly, I have to move things around, connect a keyboard and mouse... it takes a while. So, I can find that out, but not right now.

Comment: OK, so you can start the connection editing UI with `nm-connection-editor`. That would likely require X forwarding, so ssh with `ssh -X user@server`.

Comment: @mikewhatever: Oh... nice. That seems to be what I need to go forward with this. If you put your comments into an answer, I'll mark you correct.

Comment: Done! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start the connection editing UI with the `nm-connection-editor` command.

That would likely require X forwarding, so ssh with ssh -X user@server.